# Move EFI/Linux/Mac Partitions to the right order and size

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I have a Dell XPS13 laptop which I've had preinstalled with Windows, then I installed Ubuntu side-by-side. After 2 years, I decided to unify my experience at home as my work, so I installed Mac on it. I've went through boot hell but it worked out afterall.

My current `fdisk -l` shows:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E7EE13DC-4768-4B23-98F3-7BA2D9641A84

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   2099199   2097152     1G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    2099200   3123199   1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda3    3123200   3385343    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    3385344 152283135 148897792    71G Apple Core storage
/dev/sda5  152283136 153552671   1269536 619.9M Apple boot
/dev/sda6  285900800 996210687 710309888 338.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda7  153552896 157747199   4194304     2G BIOS boot

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Note that /dev/sda7 should be after /dev/sda5.

There is 66 GB free space between /dev/sda7 and /dev/sda6.

I've moved my Windows partition long ago to a separate harddisk (in the closet).

Quite a few questions I have:

1. Is there anything irreplaceable that I would lose if I remove Windows Recovery Environment and Microsoft reserved partitions?
2. How should I order my partitions to keep Mac first and Linux second? Where should EFI System/Apple boot/BIOS boot go? (I need to keep Mac first - as it is right now - otherwise Mac wouldn't boot)
3. I am assuming `dd`ing to a separate harddisk the whole partitions and writing them back to the laptop's harddisk would do the trick, provided that I fix `fstab`, right?

Comment: You will need the WRE partition if you ever want to run Windows on that machine again; I don't know about `/dev/sda3`, but it does no harm to keep a copy. I wouldn't worry about the partition order provided that the systems boot. I generally use `gparted` in Ubuntu for partition work. Ultimately it calls `dd` for copying and moving, but it makes a whole lot of checks for you.  If you call `dd` directly, make sure you use `conv=sync,noerror`. As with all partition work, make a whole disc copy before you start (or better two copies), so you can start again in case of disasters.

Comment: @AFH that's great information. I need WRE even if I have my Windows License saved? Doesn't this come in Windows' installation package? Awesome man, thanks.

Comment: I've not gone there, but I have a feeling that the WRE partition would be installed only on a full install to a blank disc, not if you try to preserve user data, programs and settings. You should be able to save the copies in a compressed file, as opposed to making a partition-to-partition copy, though this is not a `gparted` option.